# Sort by radius L.CircleMarker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i visualized my data using circlr marker. but the circle cover another circle that have smaller radius. Is it possible to sort the circle by radius. and how to do that? here is my code :

```
circles.forEach((circle) => {
  var circle = L.circle(circle.location, {
    color: "#ef8d32",
    fillColor: "#ef8d32",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    radius: circle.Transportasi_TidakMengakses * 20,
  }).addTo(map);
});

circles.forEach((circle) => {
  var circle = L.circle(circle.location, {
    color: "#cc561e",
    fillColor: "#cc561e",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    radius: circle.Transportasi_Tidak * 20,
  }).addTo(map);
});

circles.forEach((circle) => {
  var circle = L.circle(circle.location, {
    color: "#beca5c",
    fillColor: "#beca5c",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    radius: circle.Transportasi_Lainnya * 20,
  }).addTo(map);
});

circles.forEach((circle) => {
  var circle = L.circle(circle.location, {
    color: "#aa2b1d",
    fillColor: "#aa2b1d",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    radius: circle.Transportasi_Ya * 20,
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

this is the result : [image]

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Answer (score 0):

```
var circles = [
    {
        // ... other props
        Transportasi_Lainnya: 10
    },
    {
        // ... other props
        Transportasi_Lainnya: 5
    },
    {
        // ... other props
        Transportasi_Lainnya: 20
    }
]

circles.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.Transportasi_Lainnya > b.Transportasi_Lainnya ? -1 : 1
})

console.log(circles)
```

then your current code

```
circles.forEach(circle => {
    var circle = L.circle(circle.location, {
        color: '#cc561e',
        fillColor: '#cc561e',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        radius: circle.Transportasi_Lainnya*20
    }).addTo(map);
    })
```